# trim value in jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my input text box

```
input type="text" id="country" name="country" class="input_text"
```

am fecting values from database country and state from jquery

```
var country;
jQuery(function(){
$("#country").autocomplete("countries.jsp");
});
```

it is working fine but the problem is onclick of drop down value it will display that value in textbox,while displaying in textbox it is taking 5 extra space in between country and state,
any body tell me how can i trim this value having only one space in between country and state

**EDIT**

yes it is from server only in text box it is taking to much of space

```
try { 
    ResultSet rs = null; 
    java.sql.Statement stmtGet = null; 
    stmtGet = pg.gclsWFDbUtil.getDbConnection().createStatement(); 
    String query = request.getParameter("q").toLowerCase(); 
    String QueryString = "Select country,state from emp_master where country like '" 
        + query +"%'"; 
    rs = stmtGet.executeQuery(QueryString); 
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html"); 
    while (rs.next()) { 
         out.print(rs.getString(1)+""); 
         out.print(rs.getString(2)+"\n");
    }
```

Comment: Where does state come from? If this is server side data, why not just trim from the server?

Comment: u can show some of the code in detail.

Comment: yes it is from server only in text box it is taking to much of space try {
        
          ResultSet rs = null;
         java.sql.Statement stmtGet = null;
    stmtGet = pg.gclsWFDbUtil.getDbConnection().createStatement();
    String query = request.getParameter("q").toLowerCase();
          String QueryString = "Select country,state from emp_master where country like '" + query +"%'";
          rs = stmtGet.executeQuery(QueryString);
   response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
while (rs.next()) {
   out.print(rs.getString(1)+"");
   out.print(rs.getString(2)+"\n");

Comment: Edited this into your question, you can delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do **clientside**. Ideally (no, practically), this should be done **serverside**, as this won't work at all for people without JavaScript and Russian hackers who want to pwn your webapp:

```
String.prototype.innerTrim = function() {
  var temp = this;

  while (temp.indexOf('  ') != -1) {
    temp = temp.replace('  ', ' ');
  }

  return temp;
};

alert('t           es           t'.innerTrim());
// Outputs: t es t
```

---

Amazingly, this thing works almost just as fast as a regex solution. Your browser will freeze for ~10 seconds while it tests, but it'll output the execution time of each iteration: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/UrQNs/

Answer (score 1):

You could use some Regex to replace multiple whitespace characters with a single space using this JavaScript:

`str = str.replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ');`

You should really do this king of processing serverside so you have the data in the correct format before sending to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery trim, plain and simple:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

```
alert($.trim('     so much space around me    '));
```

Comment: This would only trim the whitespace at the beginning and end; the question asks how to remove 5 spaces in the middle of the string between country and state.

Comment: I understand that part, my guess here is only one of the values is creating the white space either country or state, as you can see in his while loop he has 2 out.print statements, either concatenate those two or put $.trim() around each.